# Nginx proxy_pass со скрытием ip прокси

Tags: nginx

Мне нужно проксировать запросы пользователя на другой сервер (к которому я не имею доступ), и нужно сделать так, чтобы в запросе не указывался IP сервера, а был клиента.

Как это можно сделать? Проксирование но без IP прокси.

Comment: Невозможно. . .

Comment: А есть ли какая то возможно вообще переадресовать пользователя на другой сервис с его ip без 301? Хедеры может какие то